# Angularjs polling API to check for empty array in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

Im trying to create a service that polls an API and checks to see if the response has an empty arrary.  If it does, I want it to keep checking every second until the array from the response is filled.  For instace if the array is empty the JSON will return:

```
{
choices: [ ]
}
```

To set this up I've created the service like so.  The issue is that data.response.choices.length seems to be undefined and I'm not exacly sure how to check for the array being empty.  The rest of the code seems to work fine.  Ideas?

```
angular.module('help')

  .factory('Poller', function($http, $timeout) {
    var data = { response: {}, calls: 0 };
    var poller = function() {
      if (data.response.choices.length === 0) {
        $http.get('menu.json').then(function(r) {
          data.response = r.data;
          data.calls++;
          $timeout(poller, 1000);
        });
        console.log('success');
      } else {
        $http.get('menu.json').then(function(r) {
          data.response = r.data;
        });
        console.log('damnit');
      }
    };
    poller();

    return {
      data: data
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.response` is set to an empty object, so the first time `poller` is called, `data.response.choices` is guaranteed to be `undefined`.

I think the code can be simplified to this...

```
angular.module('help')

  .factory('Poller', function($http, $timeout) {
    var data = { response: {}, calls: 0 };
    var poller = function() {
      $http.get('menu.json').then(function(r) {
        data.response = r.data;
        data.calls++;
        if (r.data.choices.length === 0) {
          $timeout(poller, 1000);
        }
      });
    };
    poller();

    return {
      data: data
    };
  });
```

Comment: quick follow up.  This worked fantastic.  However now when I add my resource to my controller and set the scope to $scope.msg = Poller.data; i get some odd issues.  For instance, if I log $scope.msg I get the entire object, but if I try to only get the resource info with $scope.msg = Poller.data.resource; it returns an empty object.  The same happens with $scope.msg = Poller.data.msg; or $scope.msg = Poller.data.calls;  Am i missing something here?

Comment: Need to see some examples of how you're using it.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/8tmbPY1eQEwk7q44gVP9?p=preview  The odd thing is that plnkr is working fine. I belive the issue is with the time it takes for the server to return the results.  In my real world app, when I try to use $scope.test = Poller.data.msg it is null.  There is a 1 second delay and the object returns everything in the inital var data {}.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<!-- Image Gallery  -->
<div class="gallery" ng-show="product.images.length">
```